# Windows 7 Boot Loader does not show

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, bootloader

I've recently installed a 32bit Windows7 in my computer. My old OS is Windows XP, and now I want to have the option to choose what OS I want to load, I've used the easyBCD to create the boot loader.

The problem is that the supposedly boot loader screen was just blank, I think it is there since whenever I boot it will be blank for 30sec and will continue to windows 7 (I tried immediately pressing enter while in this blank screen and the boot continues to window 7 directly).

So how can I make that screen appear not blank?

//Additionally, whenever I pressed the arrow down key and enter(I think this is my windows XP OS) it will just continue to be blank for a minute or so, then it will restart and will prompt me to a System Restore.

Comment: Why exactly did you use EasyBCD? If you installed Windows 7 on a different partition than the one Windows XP was installed on, the Windows 7 bootloader would automatically have added the XP entry for you.

Comment: The Win7 is in different partition than WinXP.
I've used easybcd since I thought that after you installed the Win7, I need to configure the boot loader to see that screen, but it turns that my problem is just that blank screen not showing any text what so ever.